# How can I ORDER BY the order of characters in the Persian alphabet?

Tags: sqlite, unicode, sql-order-by

In sqlite when I use `ORDER BY name ASC`, it shows 'پ' in the end of list,  while پ is third character of Persian Alphabet.
my query is:

```
select * from tb_customer order by name asc
```

How can I get it to order using the order of letters in the Persian alphabet?

I am using: java + android + android studio

Comment: Which collation do you use?

Comment: i dont know, how i can see this?

Comment: You may wish to have a read of [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3 - 7. Collating Sequences](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

Comment: What language and OS are you using?

Comment: would you mind sharing the solution?

Comment: i can't solve the problem